# How do I write a shell script that merges two separate but similar directory structures into a single directory and preserve structure?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following two directories A and B with a similar structure.  I want to merge them into a single directory shown below.

```
[root@localhost ~]# find A
A
A/dir1
A/dir1/dir11
A/dir1/file1_A.c
A/dir2
A/dir2/dir22
A/dir2/dir22/file22_A.c
A/dir2/file2_A.c
[root@localhost ~]# find B
B
B/dir1
B/dir1/dir11
B/dir1/file1_B.c
B/dir2
B/dir2/dir22
B/dir2/dir22/file22_B.c
B/dir2/file2_B.c
B/dir3
B/dir3/file3_B.c
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The output I desire is as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# find merge
merge
merge/dir1
merge/dir1/dir11
merge/dir1/file1_A.c
merge/dir1/file1_B.c
merge/dir2
merge/dir2/dir22
merge/dir2/dir22/file22_A.c
merge/dir2/dir22/file22_B.c
merge/dir2/file2_A.c
merge/dir2/file2_B.c
merge/dir3
merge/dir3/file3_B.c
```

How can I write a linux shell script that iterates through directories A and B to form the "merge" directory shown above?

Comment: `mkdir -p merge; cp -R A/. B/. merge` ?

Comment: What happened to the other question titled almost exactly the same from 2 days ago? Did you get no answer? Rather than `cp` using `mv A/* merge && mv B/* merge` would work after creating the `merge` directory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `mv` probably won't work; you'll get "Directory not empty" errors

Comment: @jhnc - you are correct -- you will be prompted to overwrite, you can use `mv -f` (`--force`) and avoid the prompt.

Comment: `-f` doesn't help here - the top-level files will get moved but subdirectories will still fail: `mkdir -p A/d B/d M; touch A/d/1 B/d/2; mv A/* M; mv -f B/* M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumptions:

- The directory tree contains regular files only.
- Filenames do not conflict in the merged destination.

How about:

```
merge="./merge"
mkdir -p "$merge"
while IFS= read -r -d "" d; do
    dir=${d#*/}
    mkdir -p "$merge/$dir"
done < <(find A B -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)

while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    dest="$merge/${f#*/}"
    cp -p -- "$f" "$dest"
done < <(find A B -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

And rsync? prepared gist: https://gist.github.com/cycle20/28c6c4abb7d08b71fcdf7b74b93f0dc0

```
bash$ rsync -a A/* B/* C
```

result check:

```
bash$ tree
C
├── dir1
│   ├── dir11
│   ├── file1_A.c
│   └── file1_B.c
├── dir2
│   ├── dir22
│   │   ├── file22_A.c
│   │   └── file22_B.c
│   ├── file2_A.c
│   └── file2_B.c
└── dir3
    └── file3_B.c
```